# OR gate with diode

Tags: digital-logic, diodes, logic-gates

Can I understand an OR gate with diodes? Why is the  output not equal to the sum of two voltages (5+5=10 v), it's confusing me?

I understood it as a binary but as a circuit I'm really confused.

Please help me.

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/172968/30062

Comment: @David the irony of that is he's just been told to not post a question as an answer on that very question.

Comment: Huh? I can't figure out what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, why would the output be equal to the sum of the voltages?

Let's examine the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBclp3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We have two voltages, \$V_{AG}\$ and \$V_{BG}\$. Both of these are \$5\mathrm{V}\$. So what is the voltage at the output?

Well, the voltage \$V_{CG}\$ cannot be higher than \$V_{AG}\$ or \$V_{BG}\$ can it. You have only \$5\mathrm{V}\$ at the supply, so how could you have more than that at the output.

Lets assume for a moment the diodes are ideal, i.e. when forward biased they have a voltage drop of \$0\mathrm{V}\$ and when reverse biased they will be open circuit. Then the output voltage will be, either:

\$V_{CG} = V_{AG} - V_{diode1} = 5 - 0 = 5\mathrm{V}\$

or

\$V_{CG} = V_{BG} - V_{diode2} = 5 - 0 = 5\mathrm{V}\$

So you can see that both cases can quite easily be true and lead to the same resultant output voltage. So in this specific case the output will be \$5\mathrm{V}\$.

Now if instead we have say, \$V_{BG} = 2\mathrm{V}\$, then the output could be either:

\$V_{CG} = V_{AG} - V_{diode1} = 5 - 0 = 5\mathrm{V}\$

or

\$V_{CG} = V_{BG} - V_{diode2} = 2 - 0 = 2\mathrm{V}\$

So how do we decide which it is? Well I can tell you that it is going to be the larger of the two voltages, in this case \$V_{AG}\$.

Why? Well if \$V_{AG}\$ is driving the output to \$5\mathrm{V}\$, so the voltage drop across diode 2 will be:

\$V_{diode2} = V_{BG} - V_{CG} = V_{BG} - V_{AG} = 2 - 5 = -3\mathrm{V}\$

As a result the diode is reversed biased, which for an ideal diode means it is open circuit. If it is open circuit then it is like \$V_{BG}\$ and \$D2\$ don't exist. If they don't exist, then you are back to a simple circuit of 1 supply.

Comment: @David fair point. I'll update that.

Answer (score 1):

Summing two voltages like that requires them to be in series. Since the diode circuit puts them in parallel there is no way that the output could possibly be the sum of the inputs.